# Как получить данные из скрытых полей таблицы?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui, плагин

Есть [демо плагина таблицы wpdatatables](https://wpdatatables.com/)

Вопрос: как в мобильном разрешении получить данные из скрытых полей таблицы (к примеру, к какому жанру относятся фильмы Adventure, Action, Science Fiction) и записать в массив?

Изначально отображаются только названия, а при раскрытии любого мы уже видим всю полную информацию по нему.
Доступ к данным возможно находится в скрытом поле зашифрованном в `json`

```
<input type="hidden" id="table_1_desc" value='{"tableId":"table_1","tableType":"mysql"...
```

Можно прямо на странице на лету прямо в консоли к нему обратиться и получить объект, но дальше не знаю, что делать, т.к. вижу только саму структуру таблицы, но не сами данные

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jQuery('#table_1_desc').val());
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: $('#table_1_desc tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)').html();

Comment: @sair что это??

Comment: если видна одна структура (без данных) значит парсить надо либо  с десктопным запросом в хедере, либо смотреть в плагин (где он их держит)